# chkdsk - ok to run on a Softare RAID1 (Intel RST)?

Tags: windows-server-2016, software-raid, chkdsk

I am running automated backups on a **Windows Server 2016** since a couple of days.

We are backing up the System as well as an entire Volume which contains the `Server Folders`. This Volume is a Software RAID1 controlled by `Intel Rapid Storage`. Besides the `server folders` directory there is another folder currently on that Volume which I have excluded from the backup.

Now, very similar to [this older post](https://serverfault.com/questions/741567/server-backup-reports-incomplete-backup-0x80070020-due-to-item-in-system-volum) I get an error message on our last backup saying:

> Error in backup of R:\System Volume Information\SRM\quota.md during write: Error [0x80070020] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

In the post mentioned above (which is 2 years old and was no solved solution) someone has suggested to check the disk (not a RAID as our scenario though) with `chkdsk`.

I, being very new to Windows Server administration and not familiar with the windows command line, am wondering whether it's safe to run `chkdsk` against a Software RAID (Intel Rapid Storage Technology). The RST Interface tells me: *"Your System is functioning normally"*

Would I need anything beyond `chkdsk R:\`?

Comment: hm, 2 upvotes definetly is nice. Anyone helping us 3 with an answer would be the cherry on the cake naturally

Answer (score 1):

Like what they put on the other answer, its not an issue with the disk/filesystem - it's that something is holding up that file (AV, WSUS, File Services). So you can either find that and stop it during the backup process or just exclude the file from VSS.

Previously the issue was that the exclude tag was not working in VSS but that should be fixed by now, I would confirm patching is up to date and exclude from VSS.

To answer your actual question - yes it should be fine to run chkdsk on a software raid although it is not needed in this scenario.

Comment: what does "VSS" stand for? @Harrison Gibbs

Answer (score 0):

CHKDSK is likely going to do nothing to fix it.  I'd use Process Explorer to see what process has a file handle open on the file listed.  Then either kill or disable that process.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @Glenn Sullivan. My concrete question was whether it is risk free to run CHKDISK against a Software RAID (Intel Rapid Storage Technology). I sense your response kinda implies a 'yes, no risk'. Do I get that correctly?